# How to get pass-through PayPal variables in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, paypal, sails.js

In HTML i passing variable like this

```
<input type="hidden" name="custom" value="custom value" />
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://mydomain.com/paypal" />
```

In Nodejs Specially SailsJS MVC what can i do to receive the returned variables ??????

Comment: I haven't tried it as yet but I'm pretty sure that if you store a variable as a cookie, and then retrieve it after payment has gone thru, should work.

Answer (score 1):

SailsJS is built on top of Express, so you can refer to [Express `req` object documentation](http://expressjs.com/2x/guide.html#req.param%28%29) to learn how to obtain request parameters.

It your particular case, it will be something like this, in your [controller](http://sailsjs.org/#!documentation/controllers):

```
var customValue = req.param('custom'),
  returnValue = req.param('return');
```

Comment: I tried it but it doesn't work for me,
paypal: function(req, res){
var custom = req.param('custom'); // undefined
}

Comment: There are too much of unknown information about your project. Please put it on github and put a link on it here. Then we'll see.